# Java JUnit - Is it possible to determine if & which exception is thrown?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, try-catch

I've got a method in a normal class that has a `try` with multiple `catches`:

```
Object returnObject = null;
try {
    // do some stuff to set returnObject
}
catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return returnObject;
```

In my `UnitTest` I would like to test if the method successfully went through the stuff in the `try`, without going into one of the `caught Exceptions`.

I know that if I didn't had a `try-catch` in my normal class' method, I could just use a `try-catch` with `Assert.fail(...);`, or an `ExpectedException-tag` in front of the test-method.

BUT, my method does have a `try-catch`, and I want to `UnitTest` if I successfully go through the `try`, without going to one of the `catches`. (As you can see in the code above, all my `catches` only have a `ex.printStackTrace();`)

PS: I also can't use the stuff in the `try` to test. So I can't check if `returnObject` is `null` after the method, because in this case I want it to be `null` (but without going to a `catch`). Otherwise I wouldn't asking this question.

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Comment: If you just `.printStackTrace()`, not a chance; this is very bad practice anyway. Can't you just throw it, or throw another exception with this one as the cause?

Comment: @fge I know it's bad practice. I didn't thought I would come in a situation like this, but here I am. And I could perhaps do `throw new AssertionException();`, but what will happen then when I go into this `catch` when I just run the normal project.. I also thought about adding a `if(unitTestBoolean) throw new AssertionException();`, where `unitTestBoolean` will be default on `false` in my normal project, and I can set it (temporarily) on `true` in my `UnitTest`. I just hoped there was an easier way to see which `Exception` is `caught` in my `UnitTests`, though..

Comment: @Joe:  This doesn't exactly read like a duplicate of that question to me.  It seems that the OP wants to *avoid* invoking an exception case.

Comment: While your question title and question body directly conflict with each other, the way I'm interpreting this is that you wish to be able to test the result of what happens inside of the `try...catch` block without throwing an exception.  It's possible to do with a mocking framework, but we would want to know more about what you're actually running inside of the `try...catch`, as well as a few other things, like if the method is on a passed-in/injected object, if it's static, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Unit test doesn't have to know has exception been thrown and catched within method or not. Your unit test should test contract of your method. And it shouldn't concern about how this contract is implemented. So if contract of the method is return null if something bad happened and it's OK then test it in this way. If invoker should know was exception or not while method was executing and type of exception, then you may return some wrapper-object with method hasException();

Answer (score 0):

You can assign exception name in a global String variable (use global - as you already returning an object), and compare the string in assert statement. If no exception case, returned string would be blank.

```
public static String message="";  // global variable

Object returnObject = null;
try {
    // do some stuff to set returnObject
}
catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
    message=ex.getMessage();
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    message=ex.getMessage();
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    message=ex.getMessage();
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    message=ex.getMessage();
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
    message=ex.getMessage();
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return returnObject;
```

And assert -

```
assertEquals(ClassName.message.equalsIgnoreCase(""),true);
```

Comment: I think adding global variable or method which task doesn't belong to whole class purpose and needed only for unit test is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree with you.But the requirement is like that.As the method is already returning a object, we have to take help of another variable.As as the variable inside the method can not be accessed outside,I suggested a global variable. Also to access it outside the class, I made it public and static.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the JVMs out put stream. We have done this with legacy code that unfortunately does not employ a logger, but prints all its information to *System.out*

For demonstration, have a look at this class that throws a given exception or none, if null is passed in the constructor. That thrown exception will be handled and printed to System.out, just like you explained in your question.

```java
public class SystemOutClass {

    private Exception exception;

    public SystemOutClass(Exception exception) {
        super();
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    public Object doStuff() {
        Object returnObject = null;
        try {
            doThrowException();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnObject;
    }

    private void doThrowException() throws NoSuchMethodException, 
    InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,
    Exception {
        if (exception != null) {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

The according test will switch the System.out to a known ByteArrayOutputStream, which then in turn can be checked for certain contents.

```java
public class SystemOutTest {

    private PrintStream defaultOutStream;

    private ByteArrayOutputStream outStream;

    @Before
    public void setupStandardOutStream() {
        outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        defaultOutStream = System.out;
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outStream));
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUpOutStream() {
        System.setOut(defaultOutStream);
    }

    private String getConsoleOutput() {
        return outStream.toString();
    }


    @Test
    public void handleNoSuchMethodException() {
        // given
        SystemOutClass handlingClass = new SystemOutClass(new NoSuchMethodException());

        // when
        handlingClass.doStuff();

        // then
        getConsoleOutput().contains("java.lang.NoSuchMethodException");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific part of a method that you'd like to test in isolation, refactor your class accordingly:

```
Object doSomeStuffAndPossiblyFail()
{
    Object returnObject = null;
    // do some stuff to set returnObject
    return returnObject;
}

Object doSomeStuffAndReportFailureAsNull()
{
    Object returnObject = null;
    try {
        returnObject = doSomeStuffAndPossiblyFail();
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    ....
    return returnObject;
}
```

You're now free to test that `doSomeStuffAndPossiblyFail` completes without throwing any exceptions.